# how to change background style/color of just one item in GalleryView/GridView?

Tags: android, xml, galleryview

I have a GalleryView widget in my android app and I would like to change the background style/color of the central item in the widget, so that it stands out from the rest. Even better, if I could make this central item bigger size than the rest.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the backgorund colour (ur choice) in the specific layout
for example you have 5 edit box 2 above 2 below and 1 in center
whom u wanna change the background color u can do the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5px" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#435232"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:maxLength="6" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:maxLength="11" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see i hav changed the background colour of 3rd edit text in the same way u can also do that

Answer (score 0):

Cerate a `selector` and set it as background of gallery items . in selector, set BackgroundColor and other features for selected state .

**selector.xml**

```
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- focused -->

 </selector>
```

**gallery_item.xml :**

```
<LinearLayout backgrond=selector.xml >

--
--

</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: I am not getting how you set the background to selector.xml in the LinearLayout. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the Android SDK source code, You should find the following directories and files:

```
/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-10/data/res/drawable-hdpi/gallery_*
/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-10/data/res/drawable/gallery_item_background.xml
```

You can copy these files to your project and create an adapter like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageItem> {

    private Context context;
    private final ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutItem,List<ImageItem> objects) {
        super(context, layoutItem, objects);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        if (convertView == null) {  
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gallery_item_background);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageDownloader.download(getItem(position).thumbnail, imageView); // or similar function to set imageView.
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Then edit xml and png files in resources directory like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- When the window does not have focus. -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/gallery_selected_default" 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_window_focused="false"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/gallery_unselected_default" 
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_window_focused="false"/>

<!-- When the window does have focus. -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/gallery_selected_pressed" 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/gallery_selected_focused" 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_focused="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/gallery_selected_default" 
    android:state_selected="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/gallery_unselected_pressed" 
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/gallery_unselected_default"/>

</selector>
```